# Dagger крашится если использую @Named

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Если удалить @Named, все работает. Но мне нужно Named

**Module**

```
@Module
public class ServerServiceModule {

ServerService mService;

public ServerServiceModule(ServerService service) {
    this.mService = service;
}

@Provides
AddLogViewModel getAddLogViewModel() {
    return new AddLogViewModel(mService.getApplication());
}

@ElementsIntoSet
@Named("area")
@Provides
Set<String> getDebugArea() {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mService.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.debugArea)));
}

@ElementsIntoSet
@Named("type")
@Provides
Set<String> getDebugType() {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mService.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.debugType)));
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class ServerService extends LifecycleService {

@Inject @Named("area") Set<String> mDebugArea;
// @Inject @Named("type") Set<String> mDebugType;

@Inject AddLogViewModel mViewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    DaggerServerServiceComponent
            .builder()
            .serverServiceModule(new ServerServiceModule(this))
            .build().stringsDebug();

            //code..
            super.onCreate();
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component(modules = ServerServiceModule.class)
public interface ServerServiceComponent {
    Set<String> stringsDebug();
}
```

**Crash**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте код компонента.

Comment: Обновил. 123456

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена так:
@Named("...") является ключом-идентификатором для @Inject 
Но, как оказалось, Если у меня 2 метода возвращают одинаковый тип, необходимо 1 метод пометить маркером @Named, а второй НЕ НАДО!

Соответственно, если 4 одинаковых метода, 3 помечаем, 1 оставляем без аннотации.

```
 @ElementsIntoSet
@Provides
@Named(AREA_TAG)
Set<String> getDebugArea() {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mService.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.debugArea)));
}

@ElementsIntoSet
@Provides
Set<String> getDebugType() {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(mService.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.debugType)));
}
```

---

А еще

```
@Component(modules = ServerServiceModule.class)
public interface ServerServiceComponent {
    void injects(ServerService service);
    Set<String> stringsDebug();
}
```